How to stop calling an api in the viewmodel from the activity's onCreate method when the configuration changes?
I have an activity and a viewmodel. The viewmodel has a callApi function. I am calling it from onCreate method.
When I change the language configuration change takes place and onCreate will be call again and api call takes place how to avoid this. I want it called only once when app launches.
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val viewmodel: MainViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        viewmodel.callApi()

        setContent {
            // ...
        }
    }
}

class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    fun callApi() {}
}


its activity cannot use onviewCreated. Is there any why to. use init{} in viewmodel and make it call only once?

@MuhammadAmmar, that won’t fix the issue because onViewCreated is also called after each configuration change.

Yes, you are right.

You actually already provided the answer in the comments.
The view model instance will be created only once, but everything in onCreate will be executed on each configuration change. If callApi should only be executed once, calling it from onCreate is not the right place.
Instead just make it private and call it in the init block of your view model:
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    init {
        callApi()
    }

    private fun callApi() {}
}

Now callApi is executed everytime when the view model is created, and that only occurs once.
